# Android Audiotrack UI freeze while write

Tags: android, user-interface, stream, audiotrack

I'm trying to play a sound continuously and I've created an audiotrack in stream mode. It works but every time the listener reacts and write a new batch of data to the buffer the UI freezes for a small time. The track along with the listeners reside in their own Thread and the thread is set with min priority.

What am I doing wrong?

For my purposes I could probably use the loop method but I want to understand how to stream sound without blocking the UI.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing the writing out on a separate thread? That's what's really important. Try using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do this. If you want extra-credit, you can read the [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) article for some nice nitty-gritty details. You should try to avoid manually creating threads. Managing them can be a pain, and there's a likely chance you might screw up. For instance, I hope you're using the [android media playback framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) to handle the actual playing of the sound for you.